# ajax request being set cookies not showing in browser

Tags: ajax

I was using $.ajax() to send a post request to my java server. I know that the my server will set a cookies when I receive this request, but the cookies doesn't appear in the browser, anyone know what happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Code, details, what have you tried?, etc.

Comment: $.ajax({
        url:'myurl',
        type:'POST',
        data: data,
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
         console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie'));        },cache: false}); but printout null even we saw the setContent on response.

Comment: The response code is 302, and I cannot get any response header in the jqXHR, they are all null. Here is what I did $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8080/',
        type:'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false
       }).always(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location'));
       });

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these parameters   (path of cookie, domain, expiry) well while setting cookies?

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myUrl,
    success: function(output, status, xhr) {
     alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("'Set-Cookie'"));
  },
  cache: false
});
```

Comment: I do check that, but it is 302 response with "Set-Cookie". Maybe my question isn't very clear, but the real question is the browser won't save it, how to make the browser save it?

Answer (score 0):

I think my question isn't very clear, it is because I am doing cross domain implementation. The cookies can't set it. I need to add "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" on the server response and add xhrFields : {withCredentials : true} in the ajax request.